# How can I modify the boyer moore algorithm so that it runs in 0(n+m) time?

Tags: java

So I'm using the Boyer-Moore function and trying to integrate the failure function from the KMP and I don't know how to do that per se. I added the calling method to the failure function but I don't know how to make use of it. The two methods are given below.

```
public static int findBoyerMoore(char[] text, char[] pattern) {
    int n = text.length;
    int m = pattern.length;
    int[] fail = computeFailKMP(pattern); ---> I did this but how can I use fail?
    if(m == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    Map<Character, Integer> last = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i = 0; i< n; i++) {
        last.put(text[i], -1);
    }
    for(int k = 0; k < m; k++) {
        last.put(pattern[k], k);
    }
    int i = m - 1;
    int k = m - 1;
    while(i < n) {
        if(text[i] == pattern[k]) {
            if(k == 0) {
                return i;
            }
            i--;
            k--;
        } else {
            i+= m - Math.min(k, 1+ last.get(text[i]));
            k = m-1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public static int[] computeFailKMP(char[] pattern) {
    int m = pattern.length;
    int[] fail = new int[m];
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    while(j < m) {
        if(pattern[j] == pattern[k]) {
            fail[j] = k + 1;
            j++;
            k++;
        }
        else if(k > 0) {
            k = fail[k - 1];
        }
        else {
            j++;
        }
    }
    return fail;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you'd have better luck with this problem at [Stack Exchange CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: It's an algorithm, not a function, and you need to implement the Galli rule to make it *O(n+m)*.